# ArrayList objects storing unexpected values

Tags: java, android, arraylist, calendar

I have a class `DailyDetails.java`

**DailyDetails.java:**

```
public class DailyDetails implements Serializable {
    Calendar calendar;
    int volume;
    int target;
}
```

I have an ArrayList (named `tempDD`).
`List<DailyDetails> tempDD = new ArrayList<>();`
I want to add objects to this arrayList with subsequent calendar values (See the code). 
`lastAppOpenedDate` and  `now` are two instances of Calendar class.
Below is the code for adding objects to arrayList in my MainActivity.

**MainActivity.java**

```
while(lastAppOpenedDate.get(Calendar.MINUTE) != now.get(Calendar.MINUTE)) {
            DailyDetails dailyDetails = new DailyDetails();
            dailyDetails.volume = waterConsumed; 
            preferences =
            PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
            if(preferences.getBoolean("default_target",true)) {
                dailyDetails.target =
                preferences.getInt("defaultTargetValue",4000);
            }
            else {
                dailyDetails.target =
                preferences.getInt("customTargetValue",4000);
            }
            dailyDetails.calendar = lastAppOpenedDate; // Adding the calendar value
            tempDD.add(dailyDetails); //Adding object to ArrayList.
            if(tempDD.size() > 30 || tempDD.get(0).calendar == tempDD.get(1).calendar) { // Can be ignored right now. 
                tempDD.remove(0);
            }
            lastAppOpenedDate.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 1); // Adding one MINUTE to lastAppOpenedDate
            waterConsumed = 0;
        }
```

dailyDetails.calendar is the point of concern.

Expected results: Every time the loop runs, one minute is added to lastAppOpenedDate calendar value. therefore,
Suppose first object in arrayList tempDD has minute value 5 then the next objects should have minute values 6,7,8,9,10,11 and so on..

But in the actual output, the minute value in calendar in each object of arrayList is same. i.e.
I added this code after the above code:

```
String s = "";
for(int i = 0; i < tempDD.size();i++){
    s = s + tempDD.get(i).calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + ",";
}
Log.d("Tag A","String: "+s);
```

This will print 12,12,12,12,12,12,12.... in the Log.

Any help would be appreciated. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do instantiate a new `DailyDetails` object on each iteration of the loop. But you assign to its `.calender` attribute always a reference - not a copy - of `lastAppOpenedDate`.

So you get a list of a dozen or so `DailyDetails` all referring to the identical instance stored in `lastAppOpenedDate`. And that one instance will naturally have the same value everytime you access it in the for-i loop, which you have updated for about a dozen times.

Change `dailyDetails.calendar = lastAppOpenedDate;` to
`dailyDetails.calendar=lastAppOpenedDate.clone();`

Comment: This is what I thought would be happening, thanks for clearing but I want a solution to this.

Comment: I did try declaring DailyDetails outside the while loop but that didnt work either.

Comment: Create copies of lastAppOpenedDate or instantiate new objects of its type for each of the DailyDetails objects. Assuming it is an NSDate then you can do: 
`dailyDetails.calendar = NSDate(lastAppOpenedDate);`

Comment: Well, no declaring and instantiating DailyDetails outside of the loop would only worsen it.

Comment: Frankly I have no idea about what NSDate is. I shall refer it and come back.

Comment: No, the other way around. Of what type is `lastAppOpenedDate` and `DailyDetails.calendar`?

Comment: And sorry for that. NSDate is the Date() equivalent in iOS. I was mistaken here. Take it as Date().

Comment: `lastAppOpenedDate` and `DailyDetails.calendar` are both instances of Calendar class in Androd.

Comment: Ok, and it is Java. :-) (sorry again) Then use `dailyDetails.calendar = lastAppOpenedDate.clone()`